# Переменная наследного класса в классе наследнике C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, наследование

У меня есть классы:

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
  string[] slots;
}
```

```
public class HumanInventory : Inventory
{
  int selectedSlot;
}
```

```
public class Entity : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Inventory inventory;
}
```

```
public class Human : Entity
{
  public HumanInventory inventory;
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы переменная `inventory` из класса `Human` заменила переменную из класса `Entity`.

Comment: Есть вариант `base.inventory` (`Human` обратится к суперклассу `Entity`) и `this.inventory` (`Human` к себе).

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужно превратить ваши поля в свойства, и в наследнике заменить get и set. Сделать это можно так.

```
public class Entity : MonoBehaviour
{
  private Inventory inventory;
  public virtual Inventory Inventory
  {
    get
    {
       return inventory;
    }
    set
    {
      inventory = value;
    }
}
```

```
public class Human : Entity
{
  public HumanInventory humanInventory;
public override Inventory Inventory
  {
    get
    {
       return humanInventory;
    }
    set
    {
      humanInventory = value;
    }
}
```

Так же послу получения Inventory из класса Human нужно будет привести его к HumanInventory. Например так

```
Human h = new Human();
int selSlot = (h.Inventory as HumanInventory).selectedSlot;
```

Comment: Проблема как раз в том, что не хотелось бы каждый раз получая инвентарь приводить его к соответствующему типу. Насколько я помню, в Java это происходит автоматически, нет ли чего то подобного в C#?

Comment: @Александр, если у вас есть такая необходимость, то вы делаете что-то не так...

Comment: @ЕгорЯсиновский если бы `HumanInventory` наследовался от `Inventory` то полеморфизм делает гетер-сетер бессмысленным. `base.inventory = new HumanInventory ();`

Comment: @Александр `C#` в отличае от `Java` типизированный. Можно написать `object inventory;` поскольку все классы так или иначе наследуются от `object`, но это будет **каламбур типизации**. `Inventory` и `HumanInventory` должны не обязательно наследоваться, но хотя бы описаны общим интерфейсом типа `IInterface inventory;`.